# perambulations -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example:

> The procedure (well actually two procedures) listing is on the next two pages. I expect that since you've gotten this far, you'll be able to follow the **perambulations** if you read carefully. Still, I'd better prepare you with a few explanatory notes first.

What exactly does that word mean? I tried to look it up online in dictionaries, but I don't think I was able to find any clear definitions for it. There was only the verb form listed in them which mostly had something to do with walking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It literally means "per" (latin: through) + "ambulation" (latin: walk). It's not that commonly used, and when it is used tends to mean "to take a walk around", like a stroll or wandering exploratory walk. Here it is meant in a less literal sense. Dictionary.com gives as its second definition that captures this use: "to traverse in order to examine or inspect". The author is going to explore the topic, and he's preparing you for the fact that it's going to be a more meandering explanation, not direct.